# OpenGL: glClientWaitSync on separate thread

Tags: multithreading, opengl, synchronization

I am using glMapBufferRange with the GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT to map a buffer object. I then pass the returned pointer to a worker thread to compute the new vertices asynchronously. The Object is doubly buffered so I can render one object while the other is written to. Using GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT gives me significantly better performance (mainly because glUnmapBuffer returns sooner), but I am getting some visual artifacts (despite the double buffering) - so I assume either the GPU starts rendering while the DMA upload is still in progress, or the worker thread starts writing to the vertices too early.
If I understand glFenceSync, glWaitSync and glClientWaitSync correctly, then I am supposed to address these issues in the following way:

A: avoid having the GPU render the buffer object before the DMA process completed:
directly after glUnmapBufferRange, call on the main thread

```
GLsync uploadSync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
glFlush();
glWaitSync(uploadSync, 0, GL_TIMEOUT_IGNORED);
```

B: avoid writing to the buffer from the worker thread before the GPU has finished rendering it:
direclty after glDrawElements, call on the main thread

```
GLsync renderSync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
```

and on the worker thread, right before starting to write data to the pointer that has previously been returned from glMapBufferRange

```
glClientWaitSync(renderSync,0,100000000);
...start writing to the mapped pointer
```

1: Is my approach to the explicit syncing correct?

2: How can I handle the second case? I want to wait in the worker thread (I don't want to make my main thread stall), but I cannot issue glCommands from the worker thread. Is there another way to check if the GLsync has been signalled other than the gl call?

Comment: You can use a separate GL context for the upload thread, which shares all the objects with your main context for drawing. In that scenario, you can also share the sync objects, and you can synchronize the threads that way.

Comment: The way I understand GLsync objects is that they are not bound to a context, so I guess the contexts would not even need to be shared. I wanted to avoid having separate contexts though for the worker threads if possible. On Android it seems to be possible to generate a native fence from a GLsync through eglDupNativeFenceFDANDROID - it'd be great if there was something alike for windows too, or platform independent.

Comment: Sync objects are objects associated to a GL context (or several shared ones) like any other GL object, so you can't get away without shared contexts.

Comment: The opengl.org wiki page on sync objects (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object) states: "Sync objects are never bound to the context, nor do they encapsulate state the way normal GL objects do. These are not OpenGL objects."

Comment: It looks like a mistake in the wiki (perhaps from an older version of sync objects?) The extension doc make it pretty clear that it works like other gl objects : https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sync.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create an OpenGL context in the worker thread, and then share it with the main thread. Next:

> Run on the main thread:
>
> ```
> GLsync renderSync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
> glFlush();
> ```

then

> Run on the worker thread:
>
> ```
> glClientWaitSync(renderSync,0,100000000);
> ```

The `glFlush` on the main thread is important, since otherwise you could have an infinite wait. See also the [OpenGL docs](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf):

> **4.1.2 Signaling**
>
> *Footnote 3*: The simple flushing behavior defined by SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT will not help when waiting for a fence command issued in another context’s command stream to complete. Applications which block on a fence sync object must take additional steps to assure that the context from which the corresponding fence command was issued has flushed that command to the graphics
> pipeline.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to have separate contexts for the worker threads, but it seems there is no way around it